# How does one use a destination MappedByteBuffer effectively?

Tags: java, nio

### Setup and question

- I'm doing a transformation on a file into a new file and don't know how large the output buffer should be

  - Encryption, encoding, compressing, etc. all have this characteristic
- If the output `MappedByteBuffer` is too small, a `java.nio.BufferOverflowException` will be thrown
- If the output `MappedByteBuffer` is too large, the resulting file will have trailing zeros
- How does one either automatically grow a `MappedByteBuffer` or chop off the trailing zeros?

### A small example

```
FileChannel inChan  = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(inString),  StandardOpenOption.READ);
FileChannel outChan = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(outString), StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

MappedByteBuffer inMBB  =  inChan.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY,  0, inChan.size());

// The following will buffer overflow after the call to transform
MappedByteBuffer outMBB = outChan.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 0);

// This will have trailing zeros after the call to transform
MappedByteBuffer outMBB = outChan.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, inChan.size() + 1024);

transform(inMBB, outMBB);
```

Comment: Last time I checked, which admittedly was a long time ago, `MappedByteBuffer` was only 20% faster than other classes for reading, and less than that for writing. There may not be any point to this.

Comment: @EJP The point is the file doesn't need to be stored in memory completely. I can read a 2GB file, transform it, and write it out to a new 2GB file without going over 300MB of RAM using `MappedByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a mapping of a different size you need to create a new memory mapping. This means either creating more mappings and stitching them together or create a new larger mapping, note ByteBuffer is limited to an Integer.MAX_VALUE size.

We developed a library `MappedBytes` which grows on demand (in chunk sizes you define) and you can truncate the file length once you know what it is.

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/MappedBytes.java

e.g.

```
Bytes bytes = MappedBytes.mappedFile(filename, 64 << 20); // 64 MB
```

Note: Bytes has built in support for chunks/files of > 2 GB, encryption and compression which might be useful.